# Use ratio for ImageView size with ConstrainLayout for Responsiveness

Tags: android, android-studio, responsive-design, responsive, android-constraintlayout

I'm using ConstraintLayout to make my app responsive to different screen size.

I want to use ratio to size my widgets.
So to use ratio I have to set my width and height to match_constraints.

So what I'm doing is :

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_img"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="250dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/img_test"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bot_img"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,125:50"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_img" />
```

So I will use margins and ratios,in dp, to set up my img size. 
The problem is that when I'm using different screen size, my img will not keep the exact ratio I want.

Can you help me ? Am I using ConstraintLayout right ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

I think you misunderstood the use of `constraintDimensionRatio`. Set your both horizontal constraints with `width="0dp"` as well as set constraintDimensionRatio (like 1:1). And set only one vertical constraint (like top) with `height="0dp"` and leave the other one (or vice-versa depending on your requirement). Now your view's width will expand as much as it can and height will adjust to the ratio. See below example for better understanding.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_img"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/img_test"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

Above code will result into a square image which will scale itself for different parent widths.

Happy codding :)